# SOAP XML Message

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I was trying to read this SOAP XML Message

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <EchoSoapRequest xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <grantapplication externalsystemreference="0743A61C-B3F8-4B51-AF1E-FBE76172D34C" externalid="d77ddae7-ad19-4c4a-b3bf-1e83df82e40f">
        <scheme>CDD</scheme>
        <applicationdate> 20170126 </applicationdate>
        <category> CDD F </category>
        <applicant>
          <title>Mr</title>
        </applicant>

      </grantapplication>
    </EchoSoapRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This is my approch

```
public bool SaveContacts(XmlDocument application)
        {

                XDocument xmessage = XDocument.Parse(application.OuterXml);


                XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";//Envelop namespace s
                XNamespace xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";//Envelop namespace s
                XNamespace soap = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";//Envelop namespace s


                XNamespace d = "http://tempuri.org/";//bookHotelResponse namespace
                XNamespace externalsystemreference = "0743A61C-B3F8-4B51-AF1E-FBE76172D34C";//d namespace
                XNamespace externalid = "d77ddae7-ad19-4c4a-b3bf-1e83df82e40f";//d namespace


                foreach (var itm in xmessage.Descendants(xsi + "Body")
                    .Descendants(externalsystemreference + "grantapplication").Descendants(externalid + "grantapplication"))
                {
                    string ss = itm.Element(d + "scheme").Value;
                }

            return true;
        }
```

But still not picking any value for ss 
can someone see anything wrong with this

Comment: You are missing open tag for </grantitem>, your XML is invalid. Try pasting your xml into a blank class via VS=>Edit=>Paste Special=>Paste XML Classes, it will give you the error message.

Comment: Removed that </grantitem> now its valid but still its not working

Comment: The descendent of body is EchoSoapRequest. You have grantapplication, then grantapplication again.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that you maintain the correct xml (as per the comments above), and that your method is truly receiving a valid "XmlDocument"; then:

```
        private static XmlDocument HisXml()
    {
        var xDoc = XDocument.Load("C:\\temp\\HisXml.xml");

        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.LoadXml(xDoc.ToString());
        return xmlDocument;
    }
```

Then, this works, word of caution, I would address possible NULLs and such, but you can handle that how you want :) : (Note, no need to do a loop through the "scheme" nodes if you KNOW you are only receiving one, you need figure that out

```
public static bool SaveContacts(XmlDocument application)
    {
        // COMMENTED CODE IS YOU OLD STUFF
        //XDocument xmessage = XDocument.Parse(application.OuterXml);
        //XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";//Envelop namespace s
        //XNamespace xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";//Envelop namespace s
        //XNamespace soap = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";//Envelop namespace s
        //XNamespace d = "http://tempuri.org/";//bookHotelResponse namespace
        //XNamespace externalsystemreference = "0743A61C-B3F8-4B51-AF1E-FBE76172D34C";//d namespace
        //XNamespace externalid = "d77ddae7-ad19-4c4a-b3bf-1e83df82e40f";//d namespace

        XmlNodeList nodeList = application.GetElementsByTagName("scheme");

        string hisStuff;
        foreach (XmlNode n in nodeList)
        {
            hisStuff = n.InnerText;
        }

        //foreach (var itm in xmessage.Descendants(xsi + "Body")
        //    .Descendants(externalsystemreference + "grantapplication").Descendants(externalid + "grantapplication"))
        //{
        //    string ss = itm.Element(d + "scheme").Value;
        //}

        return true;
    }
```